# Meteor session not getting set in Template events

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I want to show a button in my template which is shown or not dependent on a `session` value being `true` or `false`. However when I want to set the session to false in events it does not happen:

```
<template name="Home">
    {{#if reload}}
        <a class="btn btn-primary fontScale reloadBtn" href="#" id="reload"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i> Reload</a>
     {{/if}
</template>

Template.Home.helpers({
    reload: function(){
        .........
        (imgCount1 > imgCount) ? Session.set('more',true):Session.set('more', false);
        return Session.get('more');

     }
});

Template.Home.events({
    ......
    "click #reload": function(){
         Session.set('more', false);
    }
});
```

How can I set the session variable back to `false` after the button had been clicked?

Comment: 1) check in debugger that you get to your `click` event on click. It seems right but you may be missing something.    2) check what happens in your helper: you're doing a test to set `Session` to true before the `get` so are you sure this is not resetting what happened in the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your helper is keeping the session variable to true. When you click the button, you are setting the session variable, but not the image count.
If that's the case, just put some logging in both the click event and on the helper, and you might see one overwriting the value from the other.